# Socket.io connection when app goes to background

Tags: ios, swift

I am using socket.io client in swift.

Library: https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift

You know in ios when an app goes to background, probably everything is switching to suspended mode. When my app goes to background then comes to foreground after 2 minutes, this library is not connecting to server immediately. I think I have to close socket connection when app goes to background then I have to reconnect when comes to foreground.

To do this I used this methods:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    socket.reconnect()

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    socket.close()
}
```

But not worked. When app comes to foreground I completely disconnected from server.

I know this is a difficult problem to resolve. But I guessed someone using this library in Stackoverflow.

How can I handle this situtation?

Comment: hey why don't you try reconnecting in applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) and see if that works.

Comment: @Tolgay:  i'm facing the same issue,   did you found any solution for this.  if yes, please share to me.

Comment: same here with PusherSwift.